# Tic Tac Toe game by Michael Dawson, I don't understand the computer_move function?

Tags: python

I'm currently learning Python from Michael Dawson's book of Python for absolute beginner.

My problem is that I don't understand the line `def computer_move(board, computer, human)`, especially the three `for` loops inside the `computer_move` method.

```
def computer_move(board, computer, human):
    """Make computer move."""
    #make a copy to work with since function will be changing list.
    board = board[:]
    BEST_MOVES = (4, 0, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)
    print("I shall take square number")

    # if computer can win, take that move
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = computer
        if winner(board) == computer:
            print(move)
            return move
        board[move] = EMPTY

    # if human can win, block that move
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = human
        if winner(board) == human:
            print(move)
            return move
        # done checking this move, undo it
        board[move] =  EMPTY

    # since no one ca win on next move, pick best open square
    for move in BEST_MOVES:
        if move in legal_moves(board):
            print(move)
            return move
```

Comment: what don't you understand specifically about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I add more comments for the code, hope it can help. For the first loop:

```
for move in legal_moves(board):  # loop though all legal moves
    board[move] = computer       # if it's computer's turn
    if winner(board) == computer:  # if computer can win, then take the move
        print(move)
        return move
    board[move] = EMPTY
```

If the first loop do not return, which means that computer can't win with one move, then we come to the second loop. The second loop is basically same as first but the goal with this loop is to block human's winning move.

If human can't win with one move too, we come to the third loop to pick one move defined in `BEST_MOVES`.

```
for move in BEST_MOVES:            # loop though all best moves
    if move in legal_moves(board): # if the move is legal, take that
        print(move)
        return move
```

Comment: I have a question. In board[move] = computer, you said that "if it's computer's turn", I don't really understand it, my understanding is that board[move] will be computers move, is it correct or not. I don't really understand when you say "if it's computer's turn. I don't see any if statements. And last one, when return move. the for loop and the function will end or will stop running right?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's quite simple. 
First, computer checks if he (computer), can win the game with the next move. If he can win, then he perform that move. If he can't win, then he must check if user can win the game with next move. If user can win, then, computer must block that move. If user can't win the game with the next move, then you just pick the first best square option that is legal. For example, the best square is center piece. You can google this best square options.

This is prety much all that method `computer_move()` does.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I appreciate it a lot